# Qr-code decoder from image file (react native)

Tags: react-native, qr-code, expo

Im looking for a Way to decode qr-code from image file in react native (ios specifically)... I know expo provides camera scanner solution ... But im in need for file decoder

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question...**

I posted the solution that I came up with in detail [in this blog post](https://medium.com/@hend.elsahli.freelance/how-to-decode-qr-code-images-files-in-react-native-ios-and-android-b0f4dd6f5d7a)

Also the final code is [Available on Github](https://github.com/hend-elsahli/QrCodeFileDecoderSampleApp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [jsQR library](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR) to read QR codes from image files. To choose a file from storage you can try the [React Native Image Picker library](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker).

Comment: Thank you very much...

I've used expo ImagePicker to get ImageData ... and it returns it in base64 format, and I tries many methods to convert this base64 to Uint8ClampedArray used by jsQR library, but nothnig works ... any suggestions ?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but you should be able to convert it to Uint8ClampedArray like this: new UintClampedArray(Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64')). I can test it later to confirm.

Comment: I tried this one also but didn't work unfortunately, if you reach out to any solution, please help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [rn-qr-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-qr-generator) to decode a QR code in an image.

```
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';

RNQRGenerator.detect({
  uri: PATH_TO_IMAGE, // local path of the image. Can be skipped if base64 is passed.
  base64: imageBase64String, // If uri is passed this option will be skipped.
})
  .then(response => {
    const { values } = response; // Array of detected QR code values. Empty if nothing found.
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('Cannot detect QR code in image', error));
```

It will return an array of detected QR codes values
Works well on iOS and Android platforms.

Comment: Hi @Gev, I getting this error when tried your solution, any idea? ```[TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNQrGenerator.detect')]```

Comment: @Eddy Can you please provide rn-qe-generator version and the platform (iOS, Android) that you tried? and also RN version

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are trying to access the image from the image library/photos.

```
import * as RNImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner'

const decode = async () => {
  try {
    const { status } = await RNImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
     if (status === 'granted') {
       const result = RNImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          options: {
             allowsMultipleSelection: false
          }
       })
       if (result && result.uri) {
          const results = await BarCodeScanner.scanFromURLAsync(result.uri)
          console.log(results) // many information
          console.log(results.data) // May be the one you are looking for
       }
     }
  } catch (error) {
    console.debug(error)
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

- Check if the user has the permission to launch image library/photos
- Allows the user to select a image
- After selecting the image, barcode scanner spills out the information for the user

Comment: This is brilliant, this is the answer I needed.  Using the Expo libraries makes it super easy and obviously still supported. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this [react-native-qrcode-local-image](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-qrcode-local-image)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to do this, after several hours I could come up with a solution.

You need to get the image's base64 data, decode/parse it into pixel data depending on the format of the image (PNG/JPEG) and then turn that pixel data into a Uint8ClampedArray that jsqr uses

Install the following packages:

- pngjs --> To decode png image pixel data (use browserified version)
- jpeg-js --> To decode jpeg image pixel data
- buffer
- jsqr -> To detect the QRcode
- react-native-image-picker (or your image picker of choice, but do make sure it can return base64 data)

`npm i pngjs jpeg-js buffer jsqr react-native-image-picker -S`

You can use the following code to read QR code from a JPEG image from the gallery:

```
import jpeg from 'jpeg-js';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
import jsQR from 'jsqr';
const PNG = require('pngjs/browser').PNG;

const readQRFromGallery = () => {
  launchImageLibrary(
      {
        selectionLimit: 1,
        mediaType: 'photo',
        includeBase64: true,
      },
      ({ didCancel, assets, errorCode }) => {
        if (didCancel || errorCode || !assets || assets.length === 0) {
         // Handle errors here, or separately
          return;
        }

        // Get the image and its base64 data into a buffer
        const image = assets[0];
        const base64Buffer = Buffer.from(image.base64!, 'base64');

        let pixelData;
        let imageBuffer;
        
        // Handle decoding based on different mimetypes
        if (image.type === 'image/jpeg') {
          pixelData = jpeg.decode(base64Buffer, { useTArray: true }); // --> useTArray makes jpeg-js work on react-native without needing to nodeify it
          imageBuffer = pixelData.data;
        } else if (image.type === 'image/png') {
          pixelData = PNG.sync.read(base64Buffer);
          imageBuffer = pixelData.data;
        } else {
          // you can alert the user here that the format is not supported
          return;
        }

        // Convert the buffer into a clamped array that jsqr uses
        const data = Uint8ClampedArray.from(imageBuffer);

        // Get the QR string from the image
        const code = jsQR(data, image.width, image.height);

      }
    );
  };
}
```

I could  have missed some details here but I think it should be enough to guide you in the right direction