# Read QRCode from file in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, qr-code

How can I read a QRCode from a file path (not the camera) in React Native? I'm using **react-native v0.57.1**

**EDIT 1:**

With the help of @joshkmartinez I was able to write this method:

```
getImageInfo(path) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            Image.getSize(`file://${path}`, (width, height) => {
                ImgToBase64.getBase64String(`file://${path}`).then(base64String => {
                    var raw = window.atob(base64String);
                    var rawLength = raw.length;
                    var imageData = new Uint8ClampedArray(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

                    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
                        imageData[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
                    }

                    resolve({
                        width,
                        height,
                        imageData,
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    }
```

And call it using:

```
 this.getImageInfo(path).then(imageInfo => {
                    jsQR(imageInfo.imageData, imageInfo.width, imageInfo.height).then(qrcode => {
                        console.log(qrcode);
                    });
                });
```

But jsQR returns the error `Malformed data passed to binarizer`

Maybe I'm doing something wrong at the moment of converting the file to Base64, I'm using [react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64) to convert the image

**EDIT 2:**

After 2 days of research, I was able to convert the images using this method with [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs), [Buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) and [jpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js):

```
decodeImageData(image) {
        var imagePath = `${image.filePath}/${image.fileFullName}`;

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            RNFS.readFile(imagePath, 'base64').then(base64string => {
                const imageData = Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64');

                var rawImageData = JPEG.decode(imageData);

                var clampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(rawImageData.data.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < rawImageData.data.length; i++) {
                    clampedArray[i] = rawImageData.data[i];
                }

                resolve({
                    width: rawImageData.width,
                    height: rawImageData.height,
                    data: clampedArray,
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Only to discover that jsQR was not able to read any of my qrcodes (it just returns null to all of them)

Am I still missing something here? Maybe in the conversion of the image, the decoding, etc?

Comment: are you getting the image from the user's cameral roll?

Comment: no, I'm reading a folder inside the phone/sdcard

Comment: I found a similar question, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921610/8891686

Comment: thanks for the response joshkmartinez, I have actually saw that post before, but I couldn't figure out how to convert the file to an Uint8ClampedArray, could you please give some help in this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746

Comment: @joshkmartinez I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue at first when using jsQR. My goal was to detect a QR code from an image chosen in the gallery.

I found a solution by using "react-native-image-picker" and "rn-qr-generator".

```
// ... other imports ...
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';

// ...

openQRCodeFromGallery() {
   const galleryOptions = {
     mediaType: 'photo',
     includeBase64: true,
   };

  launchImageLibrary(galleryOptions, (response) => {
    if (!response || response.didCancel || !response.base64) {
      return;
    }

    const { base64 } = response;

    RNQRGenerator.detect({
      base64: base64,
    })
      .then((detectedQRCodes) => {
        const { values } = detectedQRCodes; // Array of detected QR code values. Empty if nothing found.
        // do your stuff
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         // handle errors
      });
  });
}
```

Versions used:

- react-native: 0.63.4
- rn-qr-generator: ^1.1.6
- react-native-image-picker: ^3.3.2